# Extending a measure on an algebra $\it{A}$ of subsets of $ \it{X}$ to a complete measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> Describe the process that extends a measure on an algebra $\it{A}$ of subsets of $ \it{X}$ to a complete measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra $\it{B}$ containing $\it{A}$

Trying to understand if the question is asking for an application of the [Carathéodory's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem). I was under the impression that only pre-measures can be extended to a measure on some $\sigma$-algebra. Any tips will be appreciated.

Edit: I realized this is asking for the [Completion of a measurable space](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-completion-of-a-measure-space).

Comment: You don't ask a question. What is a measure on an algebra $A$? Measures are defined as things with domains that are $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: oops, missed I mistyped the beginning of the question. It still doesn't make sense as the question does not specify $\it{A}$ as being a $\sigma$-algebra. I will assume it is.